# Famo.us + Angular.js - filter list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, famo.us

I am playing with Famo.us and Angular and I have a question regarding filtering.  I have this:

```
//LIST THAT I WOULD LIKE TO FILTER
<fa-view>
   <fa-modifier fa-size="[300,undefined]">
      <fa-surface><ul><li style="color:white" ng-repeat="track in tracks | filter:searchInput">{{track}}</li></ul></fa-surface>
   </fa-modifier>
</fa-view>


//MY INPUT I WOULD LIKE TO USE TO FILTER
<fa-surface fa-size="[400,60]">
    <center>
       <input ng-model="searchInput" type="text" />
    </center>
</fa-surface>
```

These items are not stacked directly like this but exist within the same app.  I am currently unable to filter the list at all.  I have tried to apply ng-repeat directly to the modifier with the same result.  Am I missing something?

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`searchInput` in `filter:searchInput` should be a function, not an object.

the function should return true for each value that matches the filter, and false otherwise.

so you should defined a filter function like

`function filterByInput(inputText) { return inputText == $scope.searchInput; }`

or so

and use that in `filter: filterByInput`